# android espresso: running test from command line

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a test.espresso package with all the test classes.
I am trying to run a single test class from the command line, however it ends up running all the test classes.

adb shell am instrument -w \
com.demo.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

How do I just run a single test class. I want to use bamboo(which is like jenkins) to run all the test classes individually in separate jobs.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me (the change is in bold:

`adb shell am instrument -w`**-e class full.path.and.TestClassName**`\ com.demo.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`

Based on: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html#AMOptionsSyntax (look under options for "class").

Comment: Can you provide me an example. As its bit confusing like have we want to provide the full of my project with its package name?

Comment: adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class package.name.TestClassName com.appidentifier/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

Answer (score 8):

If you're using gradle, then there is gradle task you can directly use to achieve it. It would be something like this:

`./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` - Installs and runs instrumentation tests for all flavors on connected devices.

To run on specific flavor:

```
./gradlew connectedMyAppFlavorDebugAndroidTest
```

It does everything for you, right from building the app, installing on the connected device, run the tests and finally uninstall the app.

If you're not sure about the exact gradle task you need to execute the tests, run the following to get the all available gradle tasks:

```
./gradlew tasks
```

You'll get the list of all the tasks with the short description.

Comment: ok but how would you target a single test class or package?

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding also how to run it from Gradle here.

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.MyClassTest#myFunctionTest
```

Answer (score 2):

### To run via command line

**Start device**. I use Genymotion so I would do

```
gmtool admin start DeviceName
```

---

**Install via command line**

**For ADB**

for ADB is should be exactly what the console outputs from Android studio when you start .

```
$ adb push /Users/x/x-android/app/build/outputs/apk/x-debug.apk 
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.x"

$ adb push /x/x/x-android/app/build/outputs/apk/x-debug-androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/com.x.test
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.x.test"
```

**For Genymotion it is**

```
gmtool device install ~/Desktop/x.apk 
gmtool device install ~/Desktop/x-androidTest.apk
```

**For Genymotion connect Genymotion to ADB**

`gmtool device adbconnect`

---

**Start your tests. This is for both ADB and Geny**

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.x.MyTest com.x.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Comment: List all instrumentation alternatives: adb shell pm list instrumentation